# Use DocuSign HTML / embedded responsive signing technology to replace PDF's for low vision accessibility rules

Tags: docusignapi

Looking to provide an option to State of Colorado to replace PDF's with HTML
There is a new law July 1 2024 that will allow a citizen to fine the State $3500 each time they can't access a document that would provide government services.

The State is not a fan of PDF's and have recommended using HTML instead of PDF.

Question - does DocuSign have technology to insert signature for an HTML page?

just exploring this feature

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 'insert signatures.' If you're talking about adding a signature automatically that are populated with DS info, then no -- our eSignature platform doesn't support that as a general rule.

If you're talking about adding DocuSign Signature Tabs in your HTML definitions, that we do support.

<ds-signature data-ds-recipient-id="1" name="signature"> for example should create a signature tab for recipient 1 with the name 'signature'.

We have a concept / how-to available on our DevCenter that includes the HTML parameters for our different support tabs. Feel free to reach out to our Support team if you need help.

Documentation:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/